# Session values are empty in PHP except one

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I was creating a user management system, then I stored four user sessions in an array after user has logged in. Like the following:

```
$se = new UserModel($this->pdo);
$userData = $se->get($email);

if ($userData) {
  $userDataArray = [
    'email' => $email,
    'first_name' => $userData->first_name,
    'last_name' => $userData->last_name,
    'roles' => $userData->roles
  ];
  var_dump($userData);
  $_SESSION['USER_DATA'] = $userDataArray;
}
```

but it was empty when I tried to use the first name and last_name like:

```
<?=$_SESSION['USER_DATA']['first_name'] ." ". $_SESSION['USER_DATA']['last_name']?>
```

and I print_r the $_SESSION variable which gives and showing the other array of session is empty:

```
array(1) { 
  ["USER_DATA"]=> array(4) { 
    ["email"]=> string(15) "user1@gmail.com" 
    ["first_name"]=> NULL 
    ["last_name"]=> NULL 
    ["roles"]=> NULL 
  } 
}
```

How do I solve this please?

Comment: So...what deugging have you done? All the empty fields were the ones you populated into `$userDataArray` from `$userData`. Therefore my guess is that `$userData` didn't contain these things originally. You should examine that - what does `var_dump($userData);` show you? - , and check whether the `->get()` function (as per `$se->get($email);`) is working correctly, and also whether you actually have any data in the database which is associated with the `$email` value which was provided as input.

Comment: Also...why have you tagged mysqli _and_ pdo? Surely application does not use both of them at once? And none of the code here appears to be directly related to either of them, anyway.

Comment: Please [edit] the question when you have important new information to share. Large chunks of code don't belong in the comments :-). Anyway ... `var_dump($userData) was not returning things`...well then, you need to investigate why that is. Perhaps `$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` does not return anything, for example?

Comment: But also, as per [https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php](the documentation), PDO::FETCH_ASSOC will cause it to output an array, not an object. So `$user`, if it is returned, will be an associative array. Therefore things like `$userData->first_name` would not work - it would need to be `$userData["first_name"]` to access the array element.

Comment: Move `var_dump($userData);` _before_ the `if ($userData) {` line and see what it outputs. My guess is that it shows `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add **PDO::FETCH_OBJ** to the fetch PDO function

Like this:

```
public function get($email) {
            
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE email = :email";
            
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        
            return $user;
        }
```

Why? because the $userData is being setup to fetch an Object

Answer (score -1):

**This answer is assuming your method `->get()` returns a `stdClass`**

The problem can be the validation, if your function `->get()` is returning an `stdClass`, your `if` will return true even if the object if empty. Here is an example using psysh:

```php
> $a = new stdClass
= {#2760}

> if ($a) { echo "here";}
here⏎
> $a
= {#2760}

> $a = []
= []

> if ($a) { echo "here";}
```

As you can see an empty array doesn't pass the if condition, but the stdClass does.

To fix it you can parse your stdClass into an array:

```php
if ((array)$a) { echo "here";}
```

You can also check for specific values if they exist.

Comment: the get() function is just to select by email from the database: 

`public function get($email) {
            
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE email = :email";
            
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
            return $user;
        }`